# update UI from and event

Tags: android, handler

I have a service which sends continously values to an activity through some custom event listeners.

Here everything works fine. Certain values are displayed in my activity as expected, but some others make the application to crash. This is because some of the incoming data is calculated inside a normal thread (that I cannot have access for changing it), and I know I have to use a handler here, but as far as I tried the app still crashing.

more graphically I would like to do the following

```
onValuesChanged(float val) { 
  myTextView.setText( Float.toString(val) )
}
```

where val is calculated in a normal thread, but of course it makes crash the app when doing the  setText.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of Thread and in the [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) you can update the UI.

or use Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    void run() {
        // do something interesting.
    }
});

Comment: I cannot change it since it is in a closed library. Somehow I have to get that value and do some "magic in between" to be able to update the UI with it. :(

Answer (score 1):

hey u can send a custom broadcast from your service like this

```
    Intent mintent = new Intent();
    mintent.setAction("com.action");
    mintent.putExtra("name", "value");
    sendBroadcast(mintent);
```

and register a receiver in your activity which will get the value from incoming intent and then call the handler like this to update the UI ..plese parse the int to string at receiving

```
myTextView.post(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
        myTextView.setText( Float.toString(val) )

        }
    });
```

Every time you send a broadcast to your activity and it will update the ui ..
However the above mentioned way is also right but if you have to stay with service then go for this way else above......